# OpenGL Fragment Shader not compliable

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Why wouldn't this piece of code work on a computer running a GPU with specs RTX 2080 TI on OpenGL 4.5 while it works for computers running non-Nvidia GPUs?

I tried isolating segments of the code. The below code will produce errors:

"Failed to compile fragment shader"
"Uniform variable task, modulate, uTileSize doesn't exist".

(I have helper functions to check for shader problems).

```
#version 450 core

in vec2 pos;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 uv;

out vec4 finalColor;

const vec3 C0 = vec3(1, 0, 1);
const vec3 C1 = vec3(0, 0.68, 0.94);
uniform int task;
uniform bool modulate;
uniform float uTileSize;

uniform sampler2D text;

void main(){
    if(task == 0){
        finalColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    } else if(task == 1){
        float tilePosX = floor(gl_FragCoord.x / 32);
        float tilePosY = floor(gl_FragCoord.y / 32);
        
        if(mod(tilePosX + tilePosY, 2)){
            finalColor = modulate ? vec4(C0 * color, 1.0) : vec4(C0, 1.0);
        } else {
            finalColor = modulate ? vec4(C1 * color, 1.0) : vec4(C1, 1.0);
        }
    } else if(task == 2){
        float tilePosX = floor(gl_FragCoord.x / uTileSize);
        float tilePosY = floor(gl_FragCoord.y / uTileSize);
        
        if(mod(tilePosX + tilePosY, 2)){
            finalColor = modulate ? vec4(C0 * color, 1.0) : vec4(C0, 1.0);
        } else {
            finalColor = modulate ? vec4(C1 * color, 1.0) : vec4(C1, 1.0);
        }
    } else if(task == 3){
        vec4 texture_color = texture(text, uv);
        finalColor = modulate ? texture_color * vec4(color, 1.0) : texture_color;
    } else if(task == 4){
        vec4 texture_color = texture(text, uv * 4);
        finalColor = modulate ? texture_color * vec4(color, 1.0) : texture_color;
    } else if(task == 5){
        vec4 texture_color = texture(text, uv * 4);
        finalColor = modulate ? texture_color * vec4(color, 1.0) : texture_color;
    } else if(task == 6){
        vec4 texture_color = texture(text, uv * 4);
        finalColor = modulate ? texture_color * vec4(color, 1.0) : texture_color;
    }
}
```

The following code checks if the variables exist or not:

```
void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLboolean val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform1i(loc, val);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLint val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform1i(loc, val);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLfloat val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform1f(loc, val);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform2f(loc, x, y);
  } else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform3f(loc, x, y, z);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void 
GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform4f(loc, x, y, z, w);
  } else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, glm::vec2 &val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform2f(loc, val.x, val.y);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, glm::vec3 &val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform3f(loc, val.x, val.y, val.z);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, glm::vec4 &val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniform4f(loc, val.x, val.y, val.z, val.w);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, glm::mat3 &val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniformMatrix3fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &val[0][0]);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}

void GLSLShader::SetUniform(GLchar const *name, glm::mat4 &val) {
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(pgm_handle, name);
  if (loc >= 0) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &val[0][0]);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Uniform variable " << name << " doesn't exist" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is how I am setting the uniform:

```
int task_number = 0;
bool modulate = false;
float tile_size = 16;

shdrpgms[shd_ref].Use();
shdrpgms[shd_ref].SetUniform("task", task_number);
shdrpgms[shd_ref].SetUniform("modulate", modulate);
shdrpgms[shd_ref].SetUniform("uTileSize", tile_size);
```

Any hints for me to investigate?

Comment: What is the error message? Does using an explicit `float` help (e.g. `mod(2.0F, 3.0F)`)? Does it work if you rewrite the `mod`s to `x - y * floor(x/y)`?

Comment: Error message: "Failed to compile fragment shader" and 'Uniform variable task, modulate, uTileSize doesn't exist' The error message is produced through a helper function that checks for bad shaders.

Comment: GLSL can't find the uniform variables `task`, `modulate`, and `uTileSize`. Could you try declaring them _before_ `C0` and `C1`?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! I tried putting it before C0 and C1 but the errors persist. Furthermore, I have tested the code on a RTX2080TI and a GT940MX and they both have the same problem. For reference, the code works AMD RX480 card.

Comment: Are you sure the code shown is *definitely* the code being compiled?  Please edit your question to show the exact error message(s) verbatim -- including line/column numbers if present.

Comment: I just added more context to the question. For the record, it is not a Visual Studio/C++ compilation error. The 'error' messages are from shader checking helper functions we developed.

Comment: These glUniform* wrappers add an additional layer of potential bugs. Now it looks like the shader didn't compile and as a result of that, naturally, none of the uniform values could be uploaded. Yet, we still don't know the compilation error message.
What is the string that is returned by `glGetShaderInfoLog` (which may be wrapped) after the call that tries to compile the fragment shader?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.  [Example](https://pastebin.com/dqm8wRy2).

Answer (score 1):

I took Yun's advice (profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632281/yun) written in the above comments about checking the string returned by glGetShaderInfoLog and found out that the problem lies with type conversion of

mod(tilePosX + tilePosY, 2) at lines 24 and 33 into a bool within the if condition. I addressed the problem by changing it to if (mod(tilePosX + tilePosY, 2) > 0) and there has been no complaints since.

Comment: This is actually correct behavior according to the [GLSL specifications](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) (4.1.10): there isn't a type which can be implicitly converted to a `bool`. Yet, every scalar can be converted to a bool using its constructor, e.g. `bool(2.0)`.